# Modal Popup not scrolling down in Firefox

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, modal-dialog

Hi I am using bootstrap 3 Modal Popup. It is working fine in chrome.
But, it is not working in firefox.
MY css code for .modal is:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1050;
  outline: 0px none;
}
```

If i change `top:0px` to `top:450px` then it gets displayed in firefox, too.
So i think there is some problem with scrolling of modal.
Please give any solution.

Comment: The above CSS with a bootstrap 3 modal works fine for me, also in FireFox.

Comment: works fine for me with the css you have supplied: http://jsfiddle.net/xzLjo37p/

Comment: Yes it is working when we call it from top of page, but when page height is larger than screen size and when you scroll down the page and call it from bottom of page, in that case it is not working

Comment: Well then perhaps you should have explained that in the question

Comment: Also I don't understand how it wouldn't work when you scroll to the bottom, with the modal being fixed position and full screen, it should just cover the whole screen and remove the scrollbars wherever it is called from.  Sounds to me like your position fixed is being overidden

Comment: @davidkonrad but this is default value provided by bootstrap.css if i changes it to something else then it effect display of modal-popup in chrome.

Comment: @pete i am not scrolling after calling modal-popup. first i scrolled down to the bottom of the page and then call modal-popup from there. because the button is at the bottom of page

Comment: @VinitKumarSingh - you must have something else disturbing the modal, it still works here -> http://jsfiddle.net/j7ADS/398/ try scoll down and open the modal in FF.

Comment: @VinitKumarSingh I understand the button is at the bottom but the css you have supplied for the modal means it is fixed covering the whole screen so it doesn't matter where you have scrolled to because that is what position fixed does - it is positioned relative to the viewport.  Either the styles you have provided are wrong or your computer is broken, I am thinking it is the former.  If you inspect element the modal, do you have a line through the position fixed?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.bootply.com/NOx3teQcEI.  Scroll down to the bottom and click the button, you will see the modal just pops up and covers the whole screen removing the scroll bars.  This is using your modal styles with an added blue background just to show you the modal